# How can we use HTML5 in Monocross?

Tags: html, monocross

I am developing a Monocross application so it can be supported for Android,iPhone,windows phone. In this application I want use HTMl5.

Here my Question is how can we use HTML5 in Monocross application?

Regards
Chakradhar

Comment: Hey you good question i am also looking for monocross with HTML5.        I don't know actually it will support are not, some one please help us.Thanks in advance......

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to leverage HTML5 with MonoCross.  One option is to utilize HTML based native controls within your mobile app.  This is usually done using controls like UIWebViews and WebViews (in iOS and Android respectively). All native apps have the ability to display local or remote HTML/CSS/JScript in any native controls that support HTML markup (this is true for apps leveraging the MonoCross framework too).

Another way to leverage HTML5 is to create a WebKit container for your application. By hosting your  application on an IIS web server as an ASP.NET application you can leverage the same Model and Controllers used for creating Native MonoCross applications. The difference between a native app written in MonoCross and a WebApp written in MonoCross is that the MonoCross WebKit-Container outputs views via HTML markup & ajax responses rather than concrete native views such as UIViews and Activities.